# CGAL - get Edge from Segment_2

Tags: c++, geometry, computational-geometry, cgal

I am using CGAL and I have a Polygon that I created with some vertices.

Now I get a segment, with:

```
Segment_2 segment = polygon.edge(i)
```

where `i` is an index from `0` to `polygon.size()`.

How can I transform an `Segment_2` to an `Edge`? Like there is a `t.segment(Edge e)` to get a `Segment_2` from an `Edge`, I want something to get the reverse (`Segment_2` to `Edge`).

Now I am completely sure that this segment belongs to an Edge on the Triangulation_2, how can I get it? something like `triangulation.edge(Segment_2)` maybe.

Help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have kept the two vertex handles corresponding to the two points of the segment, you can use this function:

```
bool 
CGAL::Triangulation_2< Traits, Tds >::
is_edge(Vertex_handle va,
        Vertex_handle vb,
        Face_handle & fr,
        int & i
)
```

Assuming `v1` and `v2` are the vertex handles, and `t` your triangulation object:

```
Face_handle fh;
int i;
if(t.is_edge(v1, v2, fh, i)) {
  Edge my_edge = Edge(fh, i);
  // ... use your Edge
}
```